# NodeJS fs.unlink() not releasing file handles

Tags: node.js, linux

I am using the following call to delete existing files in my nodeJS app runing on Linux (RHEL).

```
fs.unlink(downloadsFolder + '/' + file)
```

However, after a few days I noticed the files are still in the system since the file handles were not released. I restarted the node server and those files were eventually gone. How do I fix this issue programmatically?

```
dzdo lsof -L | grep -i deleted

node  48782  root 600743243   403197165 /mnt/downloads/file_1516312894734.csv (deleted)
node  48782  root 14999       403197166 /mnt/downloads/file_1516729327306.csv (deleted)
```

I also get this warning in the logs for the `fs.unlink()`, would this be causing it?

`(node:48782) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to files being marked as deleted but still taking up space? The answer below doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @ChadJohnson Nope, still waiting for it and in the meanwhile I keep restarting my node server once every few days to release those file handles.

Comment: Have you tried truncating those files? If so, is it still necessary to restart the server, and if so, why? Is there a limit to the allowed number of open file handles or something?

Comment: @ChadJohnson How do I truncate the files?

Comment: Use `fs.truncate()`. Here is how I'm doing it: `fs.truncate(sourceFilePath, () => fs.unlink(sourceFilePath, () => {}));` So, I'm truncating the file prior to deleting it. It's definitely saved the day. Should alleviate the need for you to reboot the server :)

Comment: A thought: I had what I thought was the same problem.  However, when I investigated more closely what had actually happened was that I neglected to close() the WriteStream that had written the file so it was being held onto even after it was deleted.  If you're also writing these files with a writeStream check that.

Answer (score 1):

As the warning says, the [fs.unlink](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback) method is [asynchronous](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript) which means you have to provide a callback function that will be executed when delete operation complete:

```
fs.unlink(downloadsFolder + '/' + file, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File successfully deleted');
});
```

Or you could use synchronous version of `fs.unlink`:

```
fs.unlinkSync(downloadsFolder + '/' + file);
```

Comment: are you saying that providing a callback function actually releases the file handle?

Comment: What do you mean by file handle ?

Comment: I think you answered the second part of my question about the callback warning, however the first part of the question was about fs.unlink() leaving the files in the directory and `lsof` being able to find them. They are marked as deleted but still taking disk space.

Comment: @YouneL This does not answer the question. Calling `fs.unlink()` with a callback does not release result in the release file descriptors. As @summerNight says in the comment above, files are marked as deleted but still take up space. So this question remains unanswered. The only workaround I've found thus far is to truncate files.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into the same problem and since this question has no proper solution yet, that's how I handled it;

In my case, I changed this code:

```js
const uploaded = await s3.send(newPutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: `myBucketName-${module}`,
        Key: pusher === 'storage'
            ? user + '/' + filename
            : `${user}/${fName}`,
        Body: fileStream
    }));
```

for this one:

```js
const uploaded = ctx === 'p' 
    ? await s3.send(new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: `ek-knote-${module}`,
        Key: pusher === 'storage'
            ? user + '/' + filename
            : `${user}/${fName}`,
        Body: fileStream
    }))
    : {$metadata: {httpStatusCode: 200}};
```

And then is when that bug appear.

This piece of logic only uploads a file into aws s3. The only difference is that the down below just does so when ctx (the context) has value 'p', (production). I rewrite it that way so when I'm in 'd' (development) I don't actually upload the file (because they have the bad vice to charge for resources used). The body of the object I'm sending has a constant named 'fileStream'. That is just a read stream:

```js
const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(fileRoute);
```

So it didn't happen before. So what was the bug?

For some reason I unknow, when fileStream const is used is somehow destroyed, but when I skipped that part, once the file get's unlinked still get's hanging there until the server is reboot. I think it's because the const is being held by memory (because you can't actually erease it by right clicking and selecting delete either) but don't quote me on that;

So I fixed it by actually destroying, for lack of a better word, the fileStream:

```js
    fork.on('close', async code => {

        obj.doc.destroy();

        await unlink(obj.file);

    });
```

obj is an object I have, among others, the file route (file) and the actual readStream (doc). Just destroying it before unlink it fix the problem.